# create matrix for imbalance panel data MATLAB

Tags: sql, matlab

I am very new to MATLAB.
I am currently having this dataset in matlab

```
company     date                    EDF
A           01/01/1990              0.1
A           02/01/1991              0.25
A           02/01/1992              0.4
B           02/01/1991              1.1
B           03/01/1992              1.65
C           01/01/1990              0.78
C           02/01/1991              0.89
C           02/01/1992              0.90
C           01/02/1993              0.1
```

I wanna to make it become

```
Date             A         B           C
01/01/1990      0.1                   0.78
02/01/1991      0.25      1.1         0.89
02/01/1992      0.4       1.65        0.90
01/02/1993                            0.1
```

I think we can do it with MATLAB. Can you help me with the code to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, use [textscan()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read your file:

```
f = fopen('yourFileName.txt', 'r');
data = textscan(f, '%d %d %f', 'HeaderLines', 1, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', 1, 'ReturnOnError', 0);
fclose(f);
```

then, get the years

```
years = unique(data{2});
```

now, generate the EDF values

```
edf = zeros(length(years), length(unique(data{1})))
for i = 1 : length(data{1})
    edf(find(years == data{2}(i)), data{1}(i)) = data{3}(i);
end
```

now, write them to file

```
f = fopen('newFile.txt', 'w');
fwrite(f, 'Date  Company1  Company2  Company3\n');
for i = 1 : length(years)
    fprintf(f, '%4d', years(i)); 
    fprintf(f, ' %9.2f', edf(i, :));
    fprintf(f, '\n');
end
fclose(f)
```

Now, if you really want empty entries instead of zeros, you need to add an if-clause in the fprintf loop.

Comment: Thank you so much Konstantin. It works well for that data format. However, when the company name is changed to string and date has been changed to different format, I don't know how to get it done:(.I tried for a week to find a solution but could not. If it is possible, can you please help me with it?

Comment: Did you just edited the question to become a completely different one? This is not the way you are supposed to do it. You tried for a week? Then ask more precisely what is not working in your solution. In a week you can learn MATLAB from scratch.

Comment: And, btw., if the answer worked, accept it and possibly vote it up.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin. I will ask a precise question with my code.